# Are there beneficial genetic mutations identified by consumer DNA genotyping?

Tags: dna, dna-sequencing

I'm looking at services like 23andme, and see that they identify a wide variety of genetic-based risks, like predisposition to diseases, hair loss, cancer, etc.

**Are there a more "positive" DNA analysis outcomes out there?** Like increased strength, cheerfulness(resistance to depression), etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I think it is, to a large extent, the way you perceive it. Instead of cancer-causing allele and hair-loss allele, you can think of them as cancer-protection and great-hair alleles. If you don't have disease alleles, that means that in some sense you have "life-extending" genes! Sounds much better, doesn't it?

Second of all, most funding for research is directed at disease so it is not surprising that most of the scientific knowledge is regarding this type of genetic variation.

Answer (score 1):

Lactase persistence is a recent mutation which enables the people who have it to drink and digest milk as adults, while the default state has people unable to digest milk after childhood.

There is also a loci for muscle performance. People either have fast-twitch or slow-twitch preference, which affects your sprinting vs long-distance ability. Which one is "better"? It depends!